# Unable to get value for custom app setting in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm adding a custom app settings section but I'm having trouble retrieving my newly added values. This is a .NET Core console project. Here is my config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="customAppSettings" type="MetricCollection.MetricCustomAppSettingSection, MetricCollection"/>
    </configSections>

    <appSettings>
        <add key="metricTrackers" value=".\Trackers"/>
    </appSettings>

    <customAppSettings
        productionServers="comma,seperated,list"
        qaServers="other,comma,seperated,list">

        <test
          default="testvalue" />
    </customAppSettings>
</configuration>
```

I'm able to get the productionServers and qaServers values but I am unable to get the test entry's value. I was planning on using this implementation for multiple projects so I have a base class that I inherit from. I've also tried putting it all in the child class to see if that was the issue and that didn't work either. Here's the child class:

```
public class MetricCustomAppSettingSection : BaseCustomAppSettingSection
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("test", IsRequired = true)]
    public CustomAppSettingElement Test
    {
        get { return (CustomAppSettingElement)base["test"]; }
    }
}

public class MetricConfiguration : BaseConfiguration
{
    private static MetricCustomAppSettingSection _customSection;

    static MetricConfiguration()
    {
        _customSection = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("customAppSettings") as MetricCustomAppSettingSection;
    }

    // This doesn't work...
    public static string Test
    {
        get { return GetAppSetting("Test", _customSection); }
    }
}
```

And here is the base class:

```
public class CustomAppSettingElement : ConfigurationElement
{
    #region Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// Default value which is required to be in each element
    /// </summary>
    [ConfigurationProperty("default", IsRequired = true)]
    public string Default { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Development value which is optional for each element
    /// </summary>
    [ConfigurationProperty("development", IsRequired = false)]
    public string Development { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// QA value which is optional for each element
    /// </summary>
    [ConfigurationProperty("qa", IsRequired = false)]
    public string QA { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Production value which is optional for each element
    /// </summary>
    [ConfigurationProperty("production", IsRequired = false)]
    public string Production { get; set; }

    #endregion
}

public class BaseCustomAppSettingSection : ConfigurationSection
{
    /// <summary>
    /// List of servers that are running the Production Zarga API
    /// </summary>
    [ConfigurationProperty("productionServers", IsRequired = true)]
    public string ProductionServers
    {
        get { return (string)base["productionServers"]; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// List of servers that are running the QA Zarga API
    /// </summary>
    [ConfigurationProperty("qaServers", IsRequired = true)]
    public string QaServers
    {
        get { return (string)base["qaServers"]; }
    }
}

public class BaseConfiguration
{
    #region Fields

    protected static bool _isQa = false;
    protected static bool _isDevelopment = false;
    protected static bool _isProduction = false;

    #endregion Fields

    static BaseConfiguration()
    {
        string host = IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties().HostName;
        BaseCustomAppSettingSection baseCustomSection = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("customAppSettings") as BaseCustomAppSettingSection;

        if (baseCustomSection.QaServers.IndexOf(host, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
        {
            _isQa = true;
        }
        else if (baseCustomSection.ProductionServers.IndexOf(host, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
        {
            _isProduction = true;
        }
        else
        {
            _isDevelopment = true;
        }
    }

    protected static string GetCustomAppSetting(string defaultValue, string qaValue, string devValue, string prodValue)
    {
        if (_isQa)
        {
            return qaValue ?? defaultValue;
        }
        else if (_isDevelopment)
        {
            return devValue ?? defaultValue;
        }
        else
        {
            return prodValue ?? defaultValue;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the setting designated by the key.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key">The key whose setting you want to get.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected static string GetAppSetting(string key, BaseCustomAppSettingSection customSection)
    {
        CustomAppSettingElement customSetting = (CustomAppSettingElement)customSection.GetType().GetProperty(key).GetValue(customSection);

        return GetCustomAppSetting(customSetting.Default, customSetting.QA, customSetting.Development, customSetting.Production);
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: There's no `web.config` or `app.config` in .NET Core. You don't need any of these classes to create custom settings either. .NET Core can read configuration settings from many providers that have to be configured in the application's startup. It can read from the command line, json files, environment variables etc.

Comment: The article [Essential .NET - Configuration in .NET Core](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt632279.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) explains how .NET Core configuration works. It works more or less like JSON deserialization - you create a class with the properties and nested objects you need and load it from whatever provider you use with `configuration.Get<MyAppSettingsRootClass>()`.

Comment: I ended up going with this approach. The reason I originally didn't want to was to share the base class between a .NET Core project and a .NET Framework project. Thanks Panagiotis.